# Parse Server Cloud Code: Cascade delete objects from multiple classes

Tags: heroku, promise, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

**Problem:**
Using Parse Cloud Code's afterDelete trigger to cascade-delete multiple objects from different Parse classes. For example, after a user deletes a post, I want to also delete comments AND likes associated with that post.
Let's say in Parse I have a Post, Comment, and Like class.

I think the issue(s) with my code is related to either or both of the following:
1. Using {useMasterKey: true} in the appropriate places
2. Passing the associated comments results to the associated likes results in the following then promise block so to delete them together via destroyAll()
I've searched the existing Parse-server Github issues and tried StackOverflow, forums, but haven't found anything to help resolve this.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Here's the code I've written (not working):

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Post", function(request) {
  var objectsToDelete = [];
  var commentQuery = new Parse.Query("Comment");
  commentQuery.equalTo("post", request.object);

  commentQuery.find({useMasterKey: true}).then(function(comments) {
    var likeQuery = new Parse.Query("Like");
    likeQuery.equalTo("post", request.object);
    objectsToDelete.push(comments);
    return likeQuery.find({useMasterKey: true});
  }).then(function(likes) {
    objectsToDelete.push(likes);
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(objectsToDelete, {useMasterKey: true});
  }).then(function(success) {
    console.log("successfully deleted all associated comments AND likes.");
  }, function(error) {
    console.error("Error deleting associated comments and likes " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
  });

});
```

**Expected Results**
After a user deletes a post, it should also delete the comments AND likes associated with that post.

**Actual Outcome**
None of the comments or likes associated with the post were deleted.

**Environment Setup**

parse-server version: 2.3.2 (latest)
Operating System: iOS (client) using Swift
Server Hosted on Heroku

*Any thoughts on what may be the issue here? Thank you!*

Answer (score 1):

according to documentation, `Parse.Object.destroyAll` accepts an array of objects, like

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll([object1, object2, object3])
```

BUT, I'm assuming `comments` and `likes` are arrays of objects, so you are calling it

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll([[comment1, comment2, ...], [like1, like2, ...]])
```

So, a quick fix, use `[].push.apply(objectsToDelete, array of objects)` like so

```
}).then(function(comments) {
    var likeQuery = new Parse.Query("Like");
    likeQuery.equalTo("post", request.object);
    [].push.apply(objectsToDelete, comments); // ***
    return likeQuery.find({
        useMasterKey: true
    });
}).then(function(likes) {
    [].push.apply(objectsToDelete, likes); // ***
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll(objectsToDelete, {
        useMasterKey: true
    });
}).then(function(success) {
```

alternatively, just make a single change, using `[].concat.apply([], objectsToDelete)` in the destroyAll call - i.e.

```
    return Parse.Object.destroyAll([].concat.apply([], objectsToDelete), {
```